# New-Item error in powershell

Tags: powershell

I found this interesting behavior.
Why could this happen

I am using the cmdlet New-Item for create a folder.
If I write something like this it works

```
New-Item "D:\logeando9091" -type directory
```

I have a variable of type string. It contains the value of the path where I want the new folder.

Why when Use New-Item with this variable it fails?

```
New-Item $settings.get_Item("LogFolder") -type directory
```

Here is a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string contains double quotes around it, for whichever reason, so of course this doesn't work. Remove them and you should be good:

```
$logFolder = $settings.get_Item("LogFolder") -replace '^"|"$'
mkdir $logFlder
```

You should probably fix the code that reads the setting, though.

Another way would be using `Invoke-Expression` but I wouldn't recommend it. Better to avoid it.